# Automatically accepting answers

Tags: support, accepted-answer

An answer to [What does John 3:16 mean by "perish"?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/75034/what-does-john-316-mean-by-perish) was recently marked "accepted" by the community bot.

Is this new behaviour, or have I simply never noticed it before?

Does it happen:

- where the OP user has been deleted.
- where the user hasn't logged on for a long time.
- where the user is active but hasn't bothered to accept any answer.

The linked example is an instance of the first case.

Answer (score 5):

Actually the user accepted it themselves several months before they deleted their account. You can check when it was accepted using the timeline button on the answer.

I'm not sure why it says Community rather than user38524.